# repartition after groupByKey & mapGroups operation doesn't fix data skew on a Dataset

Tags: apache-spark

I'm working on a dataset that goes through union, groupByKey & mapGroups operations.
It then goes through other operations.

I realized data is not evenly distributed after the mapGroups operation, so I ran repartition & cache right after the above mapGroups operation.
Surprisingly, data is still skewed, with almost no effect of repartition!

My first attempt was to use just .repartition(Number).

The dataset is a case class that has multiple array fields and other stuff, so I changed it to something like .repartition(Number, ds("id_field")), assuming the array field is messing up repartitioning, but still, there is no change in data skew.

I also added ds.count() operation to force trigger repartition before the final commit, and still no change in data skew.

I also tried changing ds.rdd.repartition().toDS, still no change

At this point, I'm running out of ideas.

I'm using 2001 partitions, the largest partition is ~80 MB, smallest is 2 MB.

Any idea how I can fix this data skew?

Comment: `.repartition(n)` uses simple round-robin algo to distribute the objects evenly across `n` partitions. So, if you're still observing the skew, it can only mean that some/few objects are much larger than the rest. Maybe some of the arrays you mentioned are much longer in some instances of your case class?

Comment: Yes, the array sizes are of varying sizes. I also tried `.repartition(n, ds("id_field"))` I looked at the records in the output files, the smallest has couple hundreds, and the largest has ~5K rows

Comment: Well, `.repartition(n,col)` uses hash partitioning by `col` values into `n` buckets, so uneven row distribution is not too much of a surprise in that case. How do you assess the skew after round-robin partitioning? By number of rows or by partition size?

Comment: I'm expecting number of rows to be evenly distributed. Partition size could be different because the individual rows are of different sizes

Comment: As discussed, `.repartition(n)` does distribute rows evenly. If your final dataframe is unbalanced, it could only mean that some subsequent transformation reshuffles the data again, differently.

Comment: @mazaneicha exactly, that is my understanding as well. I removed all other downstream transformations to ensure data is not further reshuffled after the last .repartition step. Will keep digging, will share in this post if I find anything interesting. Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the option of `Key Salting`. In this approach you add a new key which ensure even distribution of data. Add a new column with uniformly distributed values to the datasets and use that and the old keys to join.

Comment: I checked if there were duplicate ids in my data, and I can confirm none. Any duplicate there might have been from the union operation is removed by the groupByKey & mapGroups operation. I haven't tried salting yet, but I wonder how it will help when the Id field I used in the repartition func is already unique.

Comment: could you give a minimal example of how to do this? What does "use that and the old keys to join" mean?